# PHP mixed associative array how to get values in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, associative

Well I have something like

```
$Arr1 = array("a1" => array("a1b", "a1b"),
              "a2" => array("a2b", "a2b"),
              "a3",
              "a4",
              "a5" => array("a5b", "a5b")
);
```

meaning that "a3" and "a4" are keys without values.

I need to go through a foreach loop to get `$key => $value` pairs.

Should be something with checking of `isset($value)` but it doesn't work.

**UPDATE:**
Question is closed. Thanks to all. As it was written key without value is not a key, but value with a default integer key. So if anyone wants to use the structure above make this

```
 foreach ($Arr1 as $key => $value) { 
      if (is_int($key)) { 
           $key = $value; 
           $value = null; 
      } 
      //use $key and $value
 }
```

Comment: issset won't work - it's isset

Comment: another note: a3 is not a key, but a value as there is no label with it

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @Quasimodo's clone  if you don't know an answer or don't understand, don't write anything. Your "WTF" is not needed here at all. Find another social media for that. By the way, Maxim Fedorov already gave a correct answer that works if you are interested.

Comment: If you feel insulted, I apologize. I'm not a native speaker and for now I understood that as common speak like "Oh sh..", "Oh damn" since it is spoken/written almost everywhere in any context, not personally addressed. My US friend does so not only once a day. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each element of an array has a key. "a3" and "a4" aren't keys, they are elements which have numeric keys. You make sure it if you make `var_dump` of this array

```
array (size=5)
  'a1' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'a1b' (length=3)
      1 => string 'a1b' (length=3)
  'a2' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'a2b' (length=3)
      1 => string 'a2b' (length=3)
  0 => string 'a3' (length=2)
  1 => string 'a4' (length=2)
  'a5' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'a5b' (length=3)
      1 => string 'a5b' (length=3)
```

You can get elements with numeric keys with [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function and checking of key type (for example with help [`is_int`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) function)

```
$arr = array(
    "a1" => array("a1b", "a1b"),
    "a2" => array("a2b", "a2b"),
    "a3",
    "a4",
    "a5" => array("a5b", "a5b")
);

$newArr = array_filter($arr, function($key) {
    return is_int($key);
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

or `foreach` statement:

```
$arr = array(
    "a1" => array("a1b", "a1b"),
    "a2" => array("a2b", "a2b"),
    "a3",
    "a4",
    "a5" => array("a5b", "a5b")
);

$newArr = [];
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
  if (is_int($key)) {
      $newArr[] = $value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I came to the same thing
foreach ($Arr1 as $key => $value) {
            if (is_numeric($key)) {  
                $key = $value;
                $value = null;
            }
            //using $key
}

Answer (score 2):

Your array looks strange since you mixup keys and values like "a#". It is equivalent to:

```
$Arr1 = array
(
  "a1" => array("a1b", "a1b"),
  "a2" => array("a2b", "a2b"),
  0    => "a3",
  1    => "a4",
  "a5" => array("a5b", "a5b")
);
```

I guess you meant this one instead:

```
$Arr1 = array
(
  "a1" => array("a1b", "a1b"),
  "a2" => array("a2b", "a2b"),
  "a3" => null,
  "a4" => null,
  "a5" => array("a5b", "a5b")
);
```

Then you can access it with foreach:

```
foreach ($Arr1 as $key => $value)
  echo "$key => " .
       ( is_array($value)
           ? implode(', ', $value)
           : $value
       ),
       '<br>', PHP_EOL
  ;
```

Or if you do **not** want keys with empty values:

```
foreach ($Arr1 as $key => $value)
  if(is_array($value))
    echo "$key => ", implode(', ', $value), '<br>', PHP_EOL;
```

or just

```
$filered = array_filter( $Arr1, function($v) { return is_array($v); } );

foreach ( $filered as $key => $sub_array)
  echo $key, ' => ', implode(', ', $sub_array), '<br>', PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you set the values of "a3" and "a4" to empty array ("=> array()")?
Then you can loop through and can access the values with the "ax" keys. In a loop you process the data, except the array is empty.

Comment: I understand, but that's what I wanted to avoid.